# Show a product price based on product ID in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, elementor

This might be a stupid question, but have searched quite a lot and have still not found a way for this.

I use Wordpress, WooCommerce and Elementor on my webshop.

I update my prices about once a month. A lot of places I have a price written as texteditor or headline, and want to change that to be price coming from system.
I have tried some different ways, but so far I could not manage to make it work.

Any ideas?

I have tried use product lists, I can get the price based on product ID, but cannot style it.
I have tried with CSS shortcode, but could not make it work.
There is Product Price fields in Wordpress, but cannot make them work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with shortcode.
It's a technique in which you replace the text-based price with a shortcode which gets the product price by product ID and returns its price. This shortcode can be inserted wherever you want to display the price of a product id.

First you need to add below code to your `functions.php` file of your active theme/child theme. It is tested and works on my end.

```
// Show product price by product ID via Shortcode
function wc_price_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => null,
    ), $atts, 'woocommerce_price' ) );
    
    if( intval( $id ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
          $product = wc_get_product( $id );
          
          if ( $product->get_price() > 0 ) {
              return $product->get_price_html();
          } else { // If no price, echo text
              return __( "Price unavailable", "woocommerce" );
          }
     }
}
add_shortcode( 'woocommerce_price', 'wc_price_shortcode_callback' );
```

After you have saved your changes, you can now display the price of a product ID via the following shortcode `[woocommerce_price id="xx"]`. Replace "xx" with a product ID on your woocommerce store. Example `[woocommerce_price id="99"]`.

To make this work, you will have to replace the manually written text, with the shortcode `[woocommerce_price id="99"]`. It can be added to a text element in Elementor.

**Example in the text editor:**
[image]

**Result front-end:**
[image]

Remember that product SKU is not the same as ID.
The code can also display the price of a variant ID for variable products. The function will make sure that it is the correct price displayed, even after you change the product prices backend.

Reference: [Custom Shortcode displaying WooCommerce product price: Display a text for zero price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66365327/custom-shortcode-displaying-woocommerce-product-price-display-a-text-for-zero-p)